# Best practice to read a file and categorize it into multiple hash

Tags: perl

Say I have a file as follwing

```
myCategory1
skip some lines from reading
things that I want in the hash for myCategory2
things that I want in the hash for myCategory2
...
myCategory2
skip some lines from reading
things that I want in the hash for myCategory3
things that I want in the hash for myCategory3
...
myCategory3
skip some lines from reading
things that I want in the hash for myCategory1
things that I want in the hash for myCategory1
...
```

Now, I read the file with filehandle. The code in pseudo-format.

```
while(my $line=<FHIN>){
  chomp($line);
  if($line=~ /^myCategory1$/){
    $line=<FHIN>;           # get rid of unwanted line
    chomp($line);
    $line=<FHIN>;           # get rid of unwanted line
    chomp($line);
    $line=<FHIN>;           # this is the line of interest
    chomp($line);
    do{
      @sub_str = split(' ',$line);
      $temp_key=$sub_str[2].$sub_str[5].$sub_str[6]; #dummy assignment
      $hash{$temp_key}=$sub_str[1]; #dummy assignment
      $line=<FHIN>;         # this line cotains r.*
      chomp($line);
    }while((defined($line))&&($line !~ /^myCategory2*$/));

  }
  if($line=~ /^myCategory2$/){
    $line=<FHIN>;           # get rid of unwanted line
    chomp($line);
    $line=<FHIN>;           # get rid of unwanted line
    chomp($line);
    $line=<FHIN>;           # this is the line of interest
    chomp($line);
    do{
      @sub_str = split(' ',$line);
      $temp_key=$sub_str[2].$sub_str[5].$sub_str[6]; #dummy assignment
      $hash{$temp_key}=$sub_str[1]; #dummy assignment
      $line=<FHIN>;         # this line cotains r.*
      chomp($line);
    }while((defined($line))&&($line !~ /^myCategory3*$/));

  }
}
```

The idea is to look for Category1.....3 and capture the in between lines for further processing. Now, if I have 10 files to process each having 50 categories, according to my code, I will need 1 while loops each having 50 if..else blocks for each file, completely hard coded. How do I generalize/reduce the number of lines in my codes, that do exactly the same thing. If my question is not clear, feel free to ask!
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answers. Let me rephrase on what I need.

1. Every line of file does not contain "myCategory*"
2. There is a pattern to grep for "myCategory*"
3. I want to catch the lines that lies within two consecutive "myCategory*". So, for example, @Category_1 will have all the lines between "myCategory1" and "myCategory2"
4. How should I approach if I read the entire file into a single array and then operate based on categories.

Comment: is there a pattern more general which permits to recognize a category (double newlines, special charcter) ?

Comment: what is your expectation on the output.. please update

Answer (score 2):

I think the desired structure is to have a single loop that loops over the file and that uses state variables to decide its behaviour.

I have updated the code for the updated requirement: the beginning of a category is identified using a pattern. The filter (desired_category) allows to ignore the irrelevant categories.

```
my %hash;

my %desired_categories = map {($_ => 1)} qw(myCategory1 myCategory3);

process_file ('data2.txt');
sub process_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    my $current_category;

    open (my $fhin, '<', $filename) or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
    while(my $line=<$fhin>){
        chomp($line);
        # match pattern of the start of a new category
        if ($line =~ m/^myCategory/) {
            $current_category = $line;
            print "Start $current_category\n";
            map {scalar <$fhin>} 0..2; # skip three lines
        } elsif (exists $desired_categories{$current_category}) {
            my ($val, undef, $key1, undef, undef, $key2, $key3) = split ' ', $line;
            $hash{"$key1$key2$key3"} = $val;
            print "$key1$key2$key3 -> $val\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to also fix the two arguments open and the global file handle. It's always useful to promote best practices. :-)

Comment: I updated the question. Could you please check back. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to implement the logic:

- If there is a category name, skip a few lines.
- Otherwise, insert everything else into the hash (without regard for what category it was in).

You could do that more simply with something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

my %categories = (
   'myCategory1' => 1,
   'myCategory2' => 1,
   'myCategory3' => 1,
);

while(my $line=<FHIN>){
   chomp($line);
   if(exists $categories{$line}){
        #Skip two lines.
        <FHIN> for (1..2);
   }
   else{
      my @sub_str = split(' ',$line);
      my $temp_key=$sub_str[2].$sub_str[5].$sub_str[6];
      $hash{$temp_key}=$sub_str[1];
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if you could come up with a regex that will detect each category, you could use that and do away with the categories hash.

For example, is a category the only time that a word appears on a line by itself with no spaces?  If so, you could do:

```
   if($line =~ /^\w+$/){
```

instead of:

```
   if(exists $categories{$line}){
```

Comment: You might want to also fix the two arguments open and the global file handle. It's always useful to promote best practices. :-)

Comment: I updated the question. could you please check back. thanks.